# UICollectionView itemSize issue when resized by modifying constraint

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a horizontal scrolling UICollectionView that is inside of a cell of a vertical scrolling UICollectionView. While the vertical scrolling collectionView scrolls, the horizontal scrolling collectionView inside of it resizes based on it's presenting cell's position in the vertical collection view.

Outline of the collectionViews:

```
layout:                   scrolling:
______________________    ______________________
|         ^          |    | while   ^          |
|         | Vertical |    |   this  | scrolls: |
| __________________ |    | __________________ |
| |                | |    | |       ^        | |
| |                | |    | |       |        | |
| |<- Horizontal ->| |    | |<- This Grows ->| |
| |                | |    | |________________| |
| |________________| |    |____________________|
|____________________|    |   ______________   |
                          |   |     ^      |   |
                          |   |     |      |   |
                          |   |<-  grows ->|   |
                          |   |____________|   |
                          |____________________|
```

To change the size while scrolling, I update a width NSLayoutConstraint for the inner collectionView which updates the frame (the collectionView has other constraints to keep it's aspect ration and position correct):

```
for (constraint, definition) in parralaxDict {
    // calculates offset for each constraint
    constraint.constant = definition.parralaxOffset(forPosition: position, inRect: bounds)
}
layoutIfNeeded()
```

This works awesome, but I get a **TON** of errors regarding the flow layout's itemSize:

```
the behavior of the UICollectionViewFlowLayout is not defined because: 
the item height must be less than the height of the UICollectionView minus the section insets top and bottom values.
```

*No problem*, I thought. I'll just invalidate my layout before calling layout if needed:

```
for (constraint, definition) in parralaxDict {
    // calculates offset for each constraint
    constraint.constant = definition.parralaxOffset(forPosition: position, inRect: bounds)
}
// layout.invalidateLayout() // tried here, nope
layoutIfNeeded()
// layout.invalidateLayout() // tried here, double nope
```

Since this didn't work, I tried setting the flow layout's `shouldInvalidateLayoutForBoundsChange(newBounds: CGRect) -> Bool` to `true`. This did two things:

1. Only fired for FULL changes (i.e. fired when the CGFloat hit 1.0, 2.0, 3.0 but NOT 1.1112, 1.1345 etc..)
2. Did not fix the problem.

I also tried setting itemSize directly when updating the constraint to no avail.

It's worth noting that I did subclass UICollectionViewFlowLayout, shown below:

```
class PhotoCollectionViewFlowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {

    class func layout() -> PhotoCollectionViewFlowLayout {
        let layout = PhotoCollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.setup()
        return layout
    }

    private func setup() {
        scrollDirection = .Horizontal
        minimumInteritemSpacing = 0.0
        minimumLineSpacing = 0.0
        sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero
    }

    override func prepareLayout() {
        super.prepareLayout()

        if let theCollectionView = collectionView {
            var newItemSize = itemSize
            newItemSize.width = theCollectionView.bounds.size.width - (sectionInset.left + sectionInset.right)
            newItemSize.height = theCollectionView.bounds.size.height - (sectionInset.top + sectionInset.bottom)
            itemSize = newItemSize
        }
    }   
}
```

Any thoughts on what I can do to silence these errors?

Comment: Take a look at the methods in `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`.  There is one where you can set the item size through the layout, which I think is better than what's happening here.

Comment: Is `collectionView(_:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath:)` better than setting the size at `prepareLayout`? Isn't it less efficient to calculate the size in that function for each cell dequeue rather than once in `prepareLayout`?

Comment: Have you ever solved this? I am facing a similar problem.

Comment: @alcarv Did you solve it? Same issue here.

Comment: @tombardey I don't quite remember as this was a few years ago. If you're just talking about the constraint errors, changing the priority might help. Another thing I found over the years is that it's often easier to just calculate the size of the cell and set it manually on the flow layout.